# channel entries loop doesn't display entries added by channel form when their status is closed

Tags: safecracker, channel, status

I made a channel form. In the CP I configured the "allow guests to submit entries" and choose a guest default user in the list. In the channel preferences I choose "closed" as default status for new entries.

When I post a new entry by channel form, it creates the entry (closed) by the author I set and I can see the newly created entry in the entries list in the CP. But... when I want to display the entries in a template

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" status="open|closed" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

the ones created by channel form don't show up.

I tried to create some new entries by the CP, in this case they show up in my entries loop in my template.

What am I missing?

EE version : 2.9.0

Comment: What's the entry date look like? If it's ahead of your server time, either adjust your localization settings or add the show_future_entries parameter.

Comment: @Jim Wyse : tried to add `show_future_entries="yes"` but it didn't change anything...

Comment: Addition : if I turn the status on open, then save and re-turn the status on closed of the entry created by Channel form it appears on the loop. If it can help to find the solution

Comment: Can you open the entry in the CP Publish form after the channel form is submitted? If saved from there, does it then show up? Is the expired entry date getting filled?

Comment: @Jim Wyse : yes I can open it in the CP, yes if I save it from the CP (without changing his status (so, still closed)) I can see it in the loop. No, the expired entry date is not filled.

Comment: Can you look directly at the database and compare the data with one just submitted via channel form and one that shows up in your list. Something has to be slightly different causing your issue.

Comment: @Jim Wyse : I explored `exp_channel_data` and `exp_channel_titles` and nothing seems to be different between the two entries created (1 by channel form and one by the CP, and the two are closed). Don't know how to look then.

Comment: I still don't have found a solution, is there a bug in EE 2.9.0?

Comment: I noticed that it is not only with status closed. I tried with status open but it doesn't work either. The problem is with entries added via channel form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution :

On my entries loop I added the parameter `transcribe="disable"` and it did the trick. I have Transcribe add-on on my site and I think it interfers here because an entry added by Channel form isn't related to any trnascribe language unless I go to the CP and click on "Save" button (then it associates the entry to the default language). And, as we visit the website in 'fr' it doesn't show the entries not related to 'fr'.

So glad I have the solution. Hope this answer would help someone.

Ideally we should have a parameter (like 'transcribe_language="fr"' for example) into channel form exp tag to associate the entry created to the language we want.